# What the best portable virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization

VirtualBox, VMWare or VirtualPC/Server?
I want setup a virtual machine in a pendrive, and I'm confused about what software I use, What is best considering portability.

Thanks!

Comment: While this may be subjective, portability is a valid criteria to compare the virtualization systems against and I would re-open if I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say both VirtualBox and VMware have Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X (Intel only) support, so go with either of those. Virtual PC does not support Linux hosts (nor probably Mac OS X hosts, though I'm not sure about that).

As an added bonus, VirtualBox also supports OpenSolaris hosts, so if you want to target that platform, your choice is already made. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, VMware Player cannot be made portable, so you'd need to install it on each machine you plan to use your VM.

If that's an issue, you'd have to try with the other alternatives, although given the nature of virtualization, I'm not sure you'll be able to get it working without installing something on the host.